# My table in postgresql is truncating these strings

Tags: php, postgresql, escaping

I have a table in VMobjects like this

```
MGRCONFIG_DB=# select * from vmobjects;
               guid                |   ipaddress   | username | password |  hostid  |     vmname      | guestostype | guestos
name
-----------------------------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------------+-------------+--------
-----
 7728235734dcd25700e7c02.96324791  | gsdag         | gsdasd   |          | Physical | rag             | windows     |
 3642656604dcd343d3bcd11.54875889  | fsd           |          |          | Physical | derde           | windows     |
 17714467484dcd35dd0fa677.27764184 | dsf           |          |          | Physical | fdsfd           | windows     |
 1837080764dcd362fafe404.83675706  | fgf           |          |          | Physical | fgf             | windows     |
 2791118544dcd363df11bf1.21924610  | fdghhg        |          |          | Physical | $%^             | windows     |
 7716352574dcd365c9eb777.30236042  | dsffd         |          |          | Physical | ^               | windows     |
 10753160514dcd366631f5b6.48505657 | gfdgd         |          |          | Physical | @               | windows     |
 8253046164dcd366f177bc3.85542378  | ghgfdhg       |          |          | Physical | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@  | windows     |
 9126180214dcd367a5b42e0.23605256  | fsdfdsfdsf    |          |          | Physical | fdsaj;(         | windows     |
 11086632854dcd36f62f7e79.14470771 | dfsdfsd       |          |          | Physical | ^               | windows     |
```

Now I have a php page `addvm.php`, when I add `username/ip/password/` or anything it gets truncated

```
gets truncated on entering data as '~!@#$%^&*()_+=-`{}|\][:"';<>?/.,' for all fields.
```

After using [pg_escape_string](http://in.php.net/pg_escape_string)
i am able to insert '~!@#$%^()_=-`{}|][:"';<>?/. all strings except + and &.
@Emil Vikström: say that i have to use urlencode for this. but i don't no, How & whr it is used?

Comment: From the question phrasing I would assume you forgot to apply the correct SQL escaping function. Also whichnow: mysql or postgresql?

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:nopes about schema ..

Comment: @Stan there's a new answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/pg_escape_string) on the data before entering it into your SQL query:

```
$data = '~!@#$%^&*()_+=-';
$data_escaped = pg_escape_string($data);
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES("'. $data_escaped .'");';
```

Comment: my query is like this ....$query = "insert into vmobjects (guid,ipaddress,username,password,hostid,vmname,guestostype) values('".$guid."','".$ip."','".$username."','".$password."','".$hostid."','".$name."','".strtolower($os)."')"; where i put this ...

Comment: @stan, that means you need to call `pg_escape_string()` on all your variables when you construct your query

Comment: @Stan you should accept this answer as the correct one if it helped you. This will help other people and reward @Emil for helping you

Comment: $username_escaped = pg_escape_string($username); $password_escaped = pg_escape_string($password); $name_escaped = pg_escape_string($name); $query = "insert into vmobjects (guid,ipaddress,username,password,hostid,vmname,guestostype) values('".$guid."','".$ip."','".$username_escaped."','".$password_escaped."','".$hostid."','".$name_escaped."','".strtolower($os)."')";   i m using this

Comment: it wil not takes & and +, if i adds &+*-/|+_#$ in my username then my database show empty, when i ignore & then it shows like *-/| _#$ no + sign shows

Comment: Where do the values come from? it sounds like you are using the values directly in the URL. Please note that & and + are special characters in URL addresses. This is most important if you are writing the characters yourself directly in the address bar of the browser or similar, in which case you'll need to escape the value with urlencode *before using it in the URL*. If you on the other hand are using a HTML form they should get escaped automatically.

Comment: How do you pick which values to save? Do ou print them out lika a HTML link and then you click the link? Please provide more information - we cannot guess how your application works.

Comment: Are you writing URLs somewhere? Make sure that all URL parameters in the querystring is escaped like this: `echo '<a href="page.php?param1='.urlencode($param1).'&param2='.urlencode($param2).'">Link text</a>`